# What is the meaning of venue in this context?

Tags: meaning

> This logical
>   convergence of technology has triggered an explosion of
>   demand for virtual, searchable, content-rich data types of
>   not just text and tables, but images and sounds, and companies are working to develop advanced search routines to
>   supply this demand. The audience for these data includes
>   consumers, businesses and government organizations with the venue for interaction a virtual online data super-store.

The last sentence sounds vague to me, if not grammatically incorrect, especially the meaning of venue.

Answer (score 1):

The entire piece is some kind of marketing fluff. That's why it's shy on technical accuracy.

As for the use of "venue", they mean the "place" where the interaction takes place.

"online virtual data super-store" is redundant at best, as well as ambiguous.  Is he postulating a store of "virtual data"? That would really be *vaporware*. Does he envision an online supermarket?  Amazon already does that.

This is the kind of stuff that  "executives" read in magazines designed to convince them they know something about technology. It is not intended to be clear or accurate.